# IllegalState Fragment Not Attached to Activity ViewPager [Rare Bug]

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-resources

this curse bug is hunting me for a while. It is curse because it happens rarely and i can't find the exact reason. To Produce it;

1_Open app,i do some stuff in it and click menu button and do other stuff on other apps

2_Come back to my app after several minutes(let's say 20-30 min)and then whatever i try to do in the app that uses `getActivity().getResources()` (maybe other functions too)i get this error.

So i tried the suggestion that is given in this website `isAdded()` and it didn't work. Also how can i add this method to every `getResources` function? It would make a mess right? So as far as i read, maybe sending `Context`reference to Non-UI classes **may be** the reason for this bug but i wasn't able to catch this. I think, this bug is related to life-cycles but i couldn't figure it out. I also added static reference to `MainActivity` but it didn't work

My ViewPager Fragment Adding

```
 categoryDbApt = new CategoryDbAdapter(getBaseContext());

    tab1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
    tab2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tab2);
    tab3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tab3);
    cvp = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.cvp);
    mainLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    mainLayout.setWillNotDraw(false);
    ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
    ll.setWillNotDraw(false);
    lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0);
    sa = new SliderAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.dashboard));

    fDashboard = new FragmentDashboard();
    fExpense = new FragmentExpense();
    fExpenseAdd = new FragmentExpenseAdd();
    fIncome = new FragmentIncome();
    fIncomeAdd = new FragmentIncomeAdd();

    fragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    fragmentList.add(fIncomeAdd);
    fragmentList.add(fIncome);
    fragmentList.add(fDashboard);
    fragmentList.add(fExpense);
    fragmentList.add(fExpenseAdd);


    cvp.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
    cvp.setAdapter(sa);
    cvp.setCurrentItem(DefaultValues.startScreenPos);
```

Comment: don't use getBasecontext() for initializing. Use Activity.this instead.

Comment: try to pass the context in the slideradapter. will you please post your error log.

Comment: İ will when i can. It is very hard to catch especially since my phone has to stay connected to pc to show error.